# React Native googleUser.getBasicProfile is not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-authentication

whenever i run the code, the google window pops us and I can select the account. After I select the account i this error:
"googleUser.getBasicProfile is not a function."

Here is my code:

```
    isUserEqual=(googleUser, firebaseUser) =>{
        if (firebaseUser) {
          var providerData = firebaseUser.providerData;
          for (var i = 0; i < providerData.length; i++) {
            if (providerData[i].providerId === firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID &&
                providerData[i].uid === googleUser.getBasicProfile().getId()) {
              // We don't need to reauth the Firebase connection.

              return true; 
            }
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: What is the value of googleUser when you enter the method?

Comment: In https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/ the return object 'GoogleUser' there's not methods.

Comment: have you managed to solve?

Answer (score 0):

In [Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/) we can see that the return object of function `Google.logInAsync` is the `googleUser` of your method (i suppose, because i have the same issue with this function in [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?authuser=0)), and note that does not have any method in return of logInAsync to match with him.
So i match the `providerData[i].uid` with `googleUser.user.id`.

this is the rewritten code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < providerData.length; i++) {
   if (providerData[i].providerId === firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID &&
      providerData[i].uid === googleUser.user.id) {
      return true;
   }
 }
```